# regex to check title

Tags: javascript, regex

im competly new with regex. I have a string (javascript) and i want to check if that string contains at least 3 characters from a-z or A-Z, excluding all others characters.

I dont even know the function to check regex on a string....

Im trying to learn how to use it, but i need the expresion and function by today

thx everyone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579181/javascript-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any 3 a-z or A-Z characters anywhere in the string, you could use the regex `.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]` .

```
var testString = '09A9j0k';
var regExp = /.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]/g;
var matches = testString.match(regExp);
if(matches)
{
 //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
var s = "your string";
if(s.match(/(.*[A-Za-z]){3,}/))
{
   // 3 or more
}
```

If you want to test for more, just replace the 3 with whatever number you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var testString = '09A9j0k';
var regExp = /[a-zA-Z]/g;
var matches = testString.match(regExp);
if(matches && (matches.length >= 3))
{
 //Do Something
}
```

Other option is to use replace and count the length:

```
    var testString = '09A9j0k';
    var regExp = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
    if(testString.replace(regExp, "").length >= 3)
    {
     //Do Something
    }
```

Comment: It'll also match if you reduce test string to just '09A', which only has one A - Z character in it.

Comment: @Mark: Missed the "atleast" part. Updated the post to consider that.

Comment: @Mike: Am not sure why it would match string '09A' and also have a length >- 3. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Cybernate It's because the regex '/[a-zA-Z]/' just makes sure there's  at least one a-z letter in there, and the Javascript length check makes sure the string is 3+ letters long. '09A' is 3 letters long, and has one a-z letter, so it would pass the check. Providing the string is 3+ letters long, it doesn't check whether there's more than one a-z letter in there.

Comment: @mike: I think you misread the question/answer. Please try the code posted above and let me know if you observe the issues stated.

Comment: @Cybernate I'm willing to be corrected if I'm wrong, but what I am missing ? The OP wants a string  that "contains at least 3 characters from a-z or A-Z" : as far as I understand it, that means '09A' should not match because it only has one a-z character in it, but it does match in the code above.

Comment: @Mike: I have posted some sample code @ http://www.jsfiddle.net/5dvfE/ demonstrating the above example. Please verify and let me know if you still find an issue with above post.

Comment: @Cybernate - You're right, I was misreading the length check as length of the string rather than the length of the matches array. It does indeed work fine, sorry for doubting you!